# ComboBox values not displaying in XML view

Tags: sapui5

In my `Component.js` file, I instantiate my OData model and set it as `"donorList"`:

```js
var oDonorTable = new ODataModel(sServiceUrl/*, ...*/); // ODataModel required from "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
this.setModel(oDonorTable, "donorList");
```

In `onInit` of my view controller, I read values from backend and set it to the JSONModel:

```js
var oDnrDoc = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
oDnrDoc.read("/DonorDocs", {
    success: function(oData) {
        var oDonorDocList =  new JSONModel(); // JSONModel required from "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
        oDonorDocList.setData(oData);
        this.getView().setModel(oDonorDocList, "donorList");
    }.bind(this),
    // ...
});
```

In my XML view, I'm binding the oData values to the ComboBox in the XML view:

```xml
<ComboBox items="{path: 'donorList>/results'}">
    <c:ListItem key="{DocCode}" text="{DocDesc}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

I have nine key-value pairs coming from backend OData service for the entity set "DonorDocs". However, when rendering in the XML view, upon selecting from the dropdown list, I don't see the result (only empty values displaying) in the view although the combobox dropdown is populated with nine records.

[image: Empty dropdown display (nine records)]

I can sense some binding issue... Is the dynamic variables in curly braces causing problem? Is there a syntax issue?

Comment: i was referencing the dropdown values wrongly in the xml view. Corrected the issue and I'm now able to display the values correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have named your model as `donorList`, you have to use the name in binding.

`````
<ComboBox items="{path: 'donorList>/results'}">
    <c:ListItem key="{donorList>DocCode}" text="{donorList>DocDesc}"/>
</ComboBox> ````
`````

Answer (score 1):

> In `onInit` of my controller, I read values from backend and set it to the JSONModel [...].
>   I can sense some binding issue. Is there a syntax issue?

Adding the model name (`{donorList>DocCode}`) should solve the problem as mentioned in Dommy's answer, but there is something that should be more of a concern: missing the existing capabilities of `ODataModel` but trying to re-implement them with a `JSONModel`.

Having the OData response in a JSON format might be tempting to handle the data with a `JSONModel`, but I'd like to emphasize that **`JSONModel` is a client-side model.** It's a plain model implementation that is unaware of any contracts proposed by the service implementation (such as OData or FHIR).

The `ODataModel`, on the other hand, is a server-side model that is built explicitly for applications dealing with the OData standard (V2 or V4). It can take lots of work out of your hands. In our case, for example, simply bind the entity set **without** an intermediate JSONModel:

```xml
<!-- "donorList" == ODataModel -->
<!-- "DonorDocs" == entity set name -->
<ComboBox items="{donorList>/DonorDocs}">
  <c:ListItem key="{donorList>DocCode}" text="{donorList>DocDesc}" />
</ComboBox>
<!-- No oODataModel.read(...) in the controller -->
```

The [`ODataListBinding`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding) (resulting from `items="{donorList>/DonorDocs}"`) will format and send the request automatically for you.

---

Keep exploring what UI5 can do with OData before building the entire app with a plain JSONModel.